# Is a Fréchet differentiable map between complex Banach spaces locally given by a "power series"?

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $U \subset X$ be open. If $f:U \to Y$ is Fréchet differentiable at every point of $U$, can we locally expand $f$ as a "power series"?

To be more precise (and I hope I'm making this precise in the right way), given $x \in U$ must there exist $A_0,A_1,A_2,\ldots$ with $A_n$ a bounded, symmetric $n$-linear map $X^n \to Y$ such that the expansion
$$ f(y) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty A_n (y-x)^n $$
is valid for all $y$ in some neighbourhood of $x$? To explain the above notation:

- Let $X^0 := \mathbb{C}$ by definition so that $A_0$ is essentially an element of $Y$ (namely $f(x)$).
- Let $(y-x)^n : = (y-x,y-x,\ldots,y-x) \in X^n$ for $n \geq 1$ and let $(y-x)^0 := 1 \in \mathbb{C}$.

---

Wikipedia's entry on [infinite dimensional holomorphy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_holomorphy#Holomorphic_functions_between_Banach_spaces) seems to indicate the answer is yes. I found it pretty incredible that a classical result should hold at this level of generality so I checked out the reference they give which is Kadison & Ringrose *Fundamentals of the theory of operator algebras, vol. 1, sect. 3.3* but it turns out that only the case $X = \mathbb{C}$ is treated — pretty unsatisfactory!

I'd be interested in to know a) whether Wikipedia has this right, even though the reference is faulty, and b) how difficult is this to prove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true, you should read the book J. Mujica, *[Complex analysis in Banach Spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=t1-SH3Knz_EC)*, Elsevier, 1986. In particular Theorem 13.16 on page 107.

Comment: This is the theorem 13.16 page 107.

Comment: And the coefficients are just $A_n=D^nf(x)/n!$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to track down a copy.